# Javascript function not functioning

Tags: javascript, php, html

Ok so i have a little problem with something.
I have a javascript/DOM script that submits a user comment to a php page via ajax, and there it works excellent.

But now i need to implement it on another page, a little differently. And can't seam to make it work . Would appreciate if someone could help me point my errors.

HTML part:

```
<form name="comment-form-<?php echo $comment['comment_id'];?>" id="comment-form-<?php echo $comment['comment_id'];?>" method="POST">
    <div id="comments-approval">
        <h1><?php echo $article['naslov'];?></h1>
        <h2><?php echo $comment['comment_text'];?></h2>
        <h3>[<?php echo date('d\. m\. Y\.    H:i', $comment['comment_time']);?>]   ---   [ <?php echo $comment['comment_name'];?> ]</h3>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="article_id" id="article_id" value="<?php echo $comment['comment_article_id'];?>" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="&#x2717;" onclick="remove_comment('comment-form-<?php echo $comment['comment_id'];?>'); return false;" /> <!-- IKS -->
    <input type="submit" value="&#10004;" onclick="add_comment('comment-form-<?php echo $comment['comment_id'];?>'); return false;" /> <!-- OTKACENO -->
</form>
```

After the php foreach there are N-number of forms created, and every form has it's own unique ID

After that the moderator clicks on the button and calls the function ether ADD or REMOVE which send through the form ID in which the buttons are located.

The javascript part:

```
function add_comment(formid){

    var target = String('"#'+formid+'"');

    $(target).submit(function(){


        $.ajax({  

        type: "POST",  
        url: "approvecomment.php",  
        data: $(this).serialize(),  
        dataType: 'text',  

            success: function(msg){  
            switch(msg) {  

                    //message 
                }  
            }  
        });  
        return false;  
        });  

}
```

I know that maybe it's a dumb mistake but i really don't have a clue what am I doing wrong.

**EDIT:**

Javascript part:

```
function add_comment(formid){

    var target = '#'+formid;

    alert(target);

    $(target).submit(function(){

        alert($(this).serialize());


        $.ajax({  

        type: "POST",  
        url: "approvecomment.php",  
        data: $(this).serialize(),  
        dataType: 'text',  

            success: function(msg){  
            switch(msg) {  

                    //message 
                }  
            }  
        });  
        return false;  
    });  

}
```

Ok, so the first alert posts `#comment-form-1`

And the second does nothing.

and the form with the ID `comment-form-1` exists in the document.

Comment: Please provide the actual issue.  Are you getting a js error?  Is it hitting the file via ajax, but nothing is returned?...etc.  Spend a few minutes debugging your code, then include those results.

Comment: Problem is that the function is not entering the SUBMIT part. Just skips it and refreshes the form. I've made a check steps, just a simple alert(), when it enters that part, but nothing.

Comment: @Vladimir -- From the symptoms it sounds like a Javascript error somewhere.  Be sure to check your `console` for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already using JQuery - why not just bind the submit buttons to JQuery's .click() handler instead of hard coding it in the HTML itself?

(Note that I'm assuming your AJAX function for removing comments is "removecomment.php")

**Updated HTML:**

```
<form name="comment-form-<?php echo $comment['comment_id'];?>" id="comment-form-<?php echo $comment['comment_id'];?>" method="POST">
<div id="comments-approval">
    <h1><?php echo $article['naslov'];?></h1>
    <h2><?php echo $comment['comment_text'];?></h2>
    <h3>[<?php echo date('d\. m\. Y\.    H:i', $comment['comment_time']);?>]   ---   [ <?php echo $comment['comment_name'];?> ]</h3>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="article_id" id="article_id" value="<?php echo $comment['comment_article_id'];?>" /> 
<input type="submit" class="comment-remove" value="&#x2717;" /> <!-- IKS -->
<input type="submit" class="comment-add" value="&#10004;" /> <!-- OTKACENO -->
```

**Updated JS:**

```
//COMMENT ADD CLICK HANDLER
$("input.comment-add").click(function() {          
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "approvecomment.php",  
        data: $(this).parent().serialize(),  
        dataType: 'text',  
        success: function(msg){  
            switch(msg) {  
                //message 
            }  
        }  
    });  
    return false;
});

//COMMENT REMOVE CLICK HANDLER
$("input.comment-remove").click(function() {           
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "removecomment.php",  
        data: $(this).parent().serialize(),  
        dataType: 'text',  
        success: function(msg){  
            switch(msg) {  
                //message 
            }  
        }  
    });  
    return false;
});
```